# Rules of grammar with the word "like", "is/are"

Tags: commas

I was wondering if the comma was put in the correct place in the sentence below.

"These creatures have been shown to face negative consequences, like death."

Additionally, I was wondering if I should use is or are in this sentence.

"Most creatures, like the one that has been accounted, is/are a bit stubborn"

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, "like" is a preposition here as head of the adjunct "like death". It's normal to separate such adjuncts with punctuation such as a comma or a dash. Likewise, in your second example, the _like_ phrase is an adjunct - a supplement that is not part of the subject. The plural noun "creatures" is head of the subject noun phrase, so the verb should be the plural "are".

Comment: The comment by BillJ is correct, but I would like to add that the phrase, "like the one that has been accounted," is not idiomatic (not something that a native English speaker is likely to say), so you may wish to choose a different word than "accounted," and consider whether "most creatures are stubborn" is true. Alternatively you could say, for instance, "Many creatures, like the one mentioned above, are a bit stubborn." Welcome to EL&U! Be sure to visit the Help Center by clicking on the question-mark button on the top right of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contributor BillJ addressed this eloquently in his comment as follows:

> Yes, "like" is a preposition here as head of the adjunct "like death". It's normal to separate such adjuncts with punctuation such as a comma or a dash. Likewise, in your second example, the *like* phrase is an adjunct - a supplement that is not part of the subject. The plural noun "creatures" is head of the subject noun phrase, so the verb should be the plural "are".

I would like to add that the phrase, "like the one that has been accounted," is not idiomatic (not something that a native English speaker is likely to say), so you may wish to choose a different word than "accounted," and consider whether "most creatures are stubborn" is true. Alternatively you could say, for instance, "Many creatures, like the one mentioned above, are a bit stubborn."